# Self join for Hierarchy in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a table called `hierarchy` that has `childid` and `parentid` columns like below:

```
childid  parentid
53047    52915
52915    52914
52914    53037
52914    91856
53037    161212
91856    161212 (great great grandparent of 53047)
```

I have another table called `Names` that has a `location_id` and a `name` column. `location_id` has all the values that are in `childid` and `parentid` from the `hierarchy` table.

Now I want to get all the parent, grandparent and great-grandparent names for `childid` 53047. My output should look like below:

```
childid childname   parentname grandparentname greatgrandparentname
53047   Strasbourg  Bas-Rhin   Alsace          France
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` and join again, and again, and again.

Comment: I dont want to use too many joins,if there is a simple query using cte please let me know

Comment: multiple `left join`, one per level.

Comment: If you want to get those locations as columns, that's the easiest way. Otherwise use a recursive Select.

Comment: multiple JOINs will result in the simplest query.

Answer (score 0):

I put my answer in https://sqleditor.net/q/BkVQc9Etf

```
-- YOUR ANSWER
;WITH cte AS ( 
  SELECT childid, parentid
  , (select name from Names where location_id = childid) AS child_name
  , (select name from Names where location_id = parentid) AS parent_name
  FROM hierarchy
  WHERE childid = 53047
  UNION ALL
  SELECT hierarchy.childid, hierarchy.parentid
  , (select name from Names where location_id = hierarchy.childid) AS child_name
  , (select name from Names where location_id = hierarchy.parentid) AS parent_name
  FROM hierarchy inner join cte on hierarchy.childid = cte.parentid
)
--pivot
SELECT 53047 AS childid, 
(SELECT name from Names where location_id = 53047) AS childname,
[1] AS parentname, [2] AS grandparentname, [3] AS greatgrandparentname, [4] AS greatgreatgrandparentname, [5] AS greatgreatgreatgrandparentname
FROM
(
   -- prepare the data set
    SELECT 
    RANK() OVER   
        (ORDER BY parentid) AS Rank, parent_name
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS id, childid, parentid, child_name, parent_name
        FROM cte
    ) Z
) Y
PIVOT
(
  MAX(parent_name)
  FOR Rank IN ([1], [2],[3], [4],[5])
) AS pvt;
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://divjl040kpiqs.cloudfront.net/uploads/p/332b34fca6c162c9e133c46a15373415/RunInSQLEditor.png))</sub>
https://sqleditor.net/q/BkVQc9Etf